# actionListener method should not execute business logic if there are validation errors

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.5
I have a managed bean and doing validations in actionListener method. if it encounters any validation errors, the page should not execute the business logic. could you please tell me how to do it.

code eg:

in jsp page to display the error messages I am using p:growl:

```xml
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"  /> 

<p:commandButton value="Save"  actionListener="#(bean.save}" update=":myForm:growl" ></p:commandButton>
```

```java
public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

if(this.repeats == null || new BigDecimal("0").equals(this.repeats))
        {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(validatioHeaderMessage,"Repeats should not be blank"));  
        }

 ---- Rest of business logic.
```

So, if the above validation fails, then rest of business logic should not be executed.. how to achieve it.. do i need to use simply return "" only?

Comment: You have answered yourself. If you want to skip further processing, you need to return from the method.

Comment: What are you trying to validate? If you are validating form-values, you should use a validator, so that your save-method only contains the logic for saving. Anyway to answer your question, just like Lukasz said you can just return from the method. Use ' return; ' and not ' return ""; ' because the second one requires your method to return a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can check in your bean. But also possible to do it in your view look at this example:  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprAjaxValidations.jsf You can just use the required attribute

If you want to do it in the bean just simple do this:

```
if(repeats.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)
 {

     //Do bussiness logic
 }
 else
 {
     //Add faces message
     FacesMessage(validatioHeaderMessage,"Repeats should not be blank"));

 }
```

be careful with this kind of checks be always explicit! In your check repeats can be negative is this the case you're looking for? If so check <> 0